# Highlight Duplicates between two sheets of 2 workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macro that will compare the sheets of two workbook. And I need the row to be highlighted if found duplicate in a sheet of another workbook. So far, I have been search and I found code but I am not sure how I can highlight the cell / entire row if it found a duplicate in another sheet of another workbook. Here is my code below:

```
Sub CompareWorkbooks()

Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long



strRangeToCheck = "B2:D49"

Set wbkA = ActiveWorkbook 
Set varSheetA = wbkA.Worksheets("SAP").Range(strRangeToCheck)
Set wbkB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Request Distribution\Reminder 20170302.xls")
Set varSheetB = wbkB.Worksheets("SAP").Range(strRangeToCheck)

For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
    If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then

       'What to put to hightlight the cell / entire row

    Else

    'Some msgbox to display that there are no duplicates between sheets of 2 workbooks

    End If
Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: In case you are using office 2013 or above, you can use built in comparer for desired results,  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205148.aspx, Important:
.NET Framework 4.0 must be installed before you can use Spreadsheet Compare.

Comment: is varSheetA(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = RGB(127,187,199) not working?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I need to have it with vba as I will be putting it in a button so it will be one click for the user.

Comment: I tried to add the varSheetA(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = RGB(127,187,199). But it gives me error on the line: For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1) which is type mismatch. What could be the problem?

Comment: Now it says object required for the line: varSheetA(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = RGB(127,187,199)

Comment: You are treating varSheetA as an array, using LBound, but it is a range so loop through with a range variable.

Comment: How would I put it in a code?

Comment: Suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub CompareWorkbooks()

Dim varSheetA As Range
Dim varSheetB As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim wbkA As Workbook
Dim rFind As Range

Set wbkA = ActiveWorkbook
With wbkA.Worksheets("SAP")
    .UsedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Set varSheetA = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
Set wbkB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Request Distribution\Reminder 20170302.xls")
Set varSheetB = wbkB.Worksheets("SAP").Range(varSheetA.Address)

For Each r In varSheetA
    Set rFind = varSheetB.Find(What:=r, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        r.Interior.Color = RGB(127, 187, 199)
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am now encountering error on the line: For iRow = 1 To varSheetA.Rows.Count and it says "Object Required".

Comment: Have you tried stepping through you code? Are you using my code exactly as posted - I have changed the declarations also?

Comment: it is working now. Somehow, it is highlighting the Range B2:D49. I need to only highlight the duplicate it detects from the sheet of another workbook.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that highlights anything.

Comment: I have added what @Anil Kumar suggested which is: varSheetA(iRow).Interior.Color = RGB(127, 187, 199). I have added it after: If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then. But it only highlights the range B2:D49. How would I put it in code that will highlight the detected duplicates between sheets of 2 workbooks?

Comment: At the moment you're saying colour the cells if it's the same in both workbooks. What do you want to happen?

Comment: I have workbook(main) and workbook(2) opened. I need to compare the sheet(SAP) of workbook(main) to the sheet(SAP) of workbook(2). They have the same sheet names and columns. If there is an item from sheet(SAP) of workbook(main) existing in sheet(SAP) of Workbook(2). Then I need the cell / entire row of the item in sheet(SAP) of workbook(main) be highlighted. In the case of above code, it highlights the range B2:D49.

Comment: I've amended the code above which should not highlight the whole range. So you're saying that if it exists anywhere in workbook(2) it should be highlighted, not only if it is in the same cell?

Comment: I have tried the code above but it still highlighted the defined range which is B2:D49. Yes, because item might be in the different cell in the next days. It's like I need to find duplicate in sheet 1 and sheet 2 and highlight the cell / item if it exists in sheet 2.

Comment: I have tried above code and it says that: "Invalid next control variable reference" on the line Next iRow.

Comment: I got the next's the wrong way round - corrected above. Just need to swap variables.

Comment: Hi SJR I have tried the code but it is still the same. Highlighting the Range B2:D49..

Comment: Have you cleared the range of formatting before you run the code?

Comment: Yes, I have cleared the range. Actually I have deleted the sheet and created again. Maybe this declaration has something to do with it that's why it highlights B2:D49 --> strRangeToCheck = "B2:D49"

Comment: If you can try once more as I spotted a small typo in the code (doubt it will make much difference though). Are there definitely values in sheetA that are not in sheetB?

Comment: Yes there are. I tried it now and it seems to be working. It highlights an item in sheetA which is existing in SheetB and ignores that are not duplicate. Somehow, it highlights what ever range I declare in strRangeToCheck. Like for example I changed the value to B2:B100. I have items from B2 til B6. And only B2 is highlight which is actually existing in sheetB. So this is already correct. Somehow, the highlight continues from B7 until B100. Could this be related to it?

Comment: Well I suppose a blank cell would be regarded as duplicate. If the range you want to check in sheetA is going to change then the code should be amended. Will it always start in B2, and could it be any number of rows and columns?

Comment: The other question is, will you always be checking the same range in sheetB as sheetA?

Comment: Oh ok. Yes it always starts at B2 as I have a header in B1. There are no definite number of rows, but in column yes, and the column will always 4.Currently I have 5 items starting B2 til B6. And tomorrow or any other day, it will change. -- The purpose of this is to highlight the item that is not posted from yesterday. So this feature will be very helpful to remind the user to process it so it will be removed from the list on the other day. Just to give you background of it. :)

Comment: I've amended code above once more so let me know how it goes.

Comment: To answer the other question. Actually, I needed to only check the rows in a certain column. Like for this example, I am checking column B if there are any rows that are duplicate from SheetA to SheetB.

Comment: I tried it and it is almost working to what I needed! :) Somehow, could you please help amend the code that it will only search in column B? As I have checked, column B is working fine. But I think it searches also on the other column. With this, it highlights when there are some blanks on the other column. I only need it to be in Column B.

Comment: Off we go again! Amended above.

Comment: I have 4 columns and when there are any blanks / same value on columns A, C, D it highlights also. I would like to focus on column B only.

Comment: Hi :)  It still highlights the rows of other columns. I needed it only to be highlighted the duplicate row in column B.

Comment: I think you probably need to clear all formatting before you start. Henceforth, the code should take care of it.

Comment: I have cleared everything before starting to test again. I have column A, B, C and D. The code above works fine with the rows of Column B. And highlights the duplicate(which is working fine). Somehow, it seems that it is also search in the other columns. In this case, all rows of other columns are highlighted. I would like to focus on the data in column B and highlight it when it's a duplicate in SheetB.

Comment: I have simplified the code above, but I don't see how that can be happening as it is only looking at column B.

Comment: Thanks, SJR, I will try after 30 mins. And will let you. I'll be back. :)

Comment: Tested it and works the way I wanted it. Thanks SJR! Up you go! :)